# Как в java-приложении вывести все application.properties в лог

Tags: java, логирование

Java-приложение.

```
private Properties additionalProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
    properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql", "true");
    properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    return properties;
}
```

Как мне вывести в лог все переменные.
Не получается включить логирование для hibernate. Попытаюсь для начала проверить, записаны ли данные параметры в приложение.

Comment: Используете spring-boot? Тогда подключите [actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/production-ready-enabling.html) и смотрите все свойства по урлу `/actuator/env`

Comment: Без шансов. Хибернет удаляет свои переменные после старта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Победил следующим кодом:

```
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", "true");
```

Проблема была связана с тем, что неверно прописывал называния свойств.